# Using a MCU's UART as DAC

Tags: microcontroller, uart, dac

Many simple MCUs do not provide DACs despite having PWM output. For low clock frequencies like 8MHz, PWM does provide very poor quality if used for audio purposes. E.g., TI mentions in application notes that 32kHz PWM with 8 bit timing resolution would result in an analog signal quality compared to 4-5 bit resolution DAC.

I wonder if one would be better off using UART TX at the highest possible baud rate - e.g. some MCUs would push out up to 400kBit/s at 16MHz.

Compared to the PWM method with its 8 or 16 MHz time base, we have only 400kHz timing resolution for each bit, but on the other hand, we may do far more level switchings in some given interval.

- 32kHz PWM does 64k switches per second with an 16Mhz timing resolution.
- 400kBaud UART allows for 400k switches per second with 400k timing resolution.

If we convert 50k samples per second to 50k 8-bit dithering patterns, what effective audio signal quality can be expected?

Comment: The theory is nice. But implementing it in practice wouldn't be easy... UARTs have no built-in facilities to send pulse trains with variable frequencies. Much hacking would be involved, if possible at all.

Comment: This is really not clear. Is the idea to have the UART TX pin as a PWM (which means having a RC filter directly on the TX pin) ? Or use the UART to transmit samples to an external DAC ?

Comment: @dim I think it's the former.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then, how could UART provide better audio quality ? On all MCUs I've met, PWM frequency is way higher than the UART max baud rate. The 400kBaud is to be compared to the 8MHz main PWM frequency, not to the 32KHz sample rate frequency. I don't understand his maths.

Comment: @dim For some reason the OP is assuming that the PWM frequency is 32KHz...

Comment: Delta-sigma is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: Main problem is that an UART has pretty crappy baudrate accuracy. Depending on what clock divisors there are, you sometimes end up with an error, which is much larger than what you would get from the PWM.

Comment: Also, the resolution of the PWM will be the amount of timer ticks that you are able to divide your PWM period into, simple as that. What actual resolution you end up with after the op amps etc that convert the PWM to an analog voltage, entirely depends on the accuracy of the components involved. The advantage of a hardware DAC is that it will have these components built-in, except capacitors. You'll want to focus on these components, rather than what's inside the MCU.

Comment: interesting idea and doable, but perhaps not to the accuracy/quality you desire.  so many other microcontrollers out there from ti and other places, just spend the buck fifty and get another.  one with a pwm

Comment: @Lundin If you want to end up with a certain minimum signal frequency (which is something that seems to happen in Audio, weirdly) you can't just say "Bah, I'll use 16bit PWM and see what comes out". That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think something may have gone wrong in interpretation of an un-linked, and thus unknown app-sheet, where they assume a (common) 32kHz desired audio 'sample rate', which is only a factor 250 below a main clock of 8MHz and thus creating a very low available accuracy in the divisional PWM system. With 16MHz clock, it'd start sounding reasonably like audio, but not of any respectable quality.

Comment: [Definitely possible. Quality questionable.](http://hackaday.com/2016/04/11/audio-out-over-uart/)

Comment: [I've done this to play music on my graphing calculator.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMJV8He9HCE)

Comment: Well, my 32kHz PWM variant sounds far better then this calculator :-)  so I should keep PWM it seems.

Comment: @Lundin The error in the baud rate won't affect him. He'll just adjust his dithering to match the actual baud rate (which he can easily compute). He's not trying to get some specific baud rate, he just wants as much as possible. He'll get specific output frequencies by dithering.

Comment: @pjc50 Software-controlled delta-sigma in an MCU, seriously? Didn't know people wanted to do that. :P

Comment: @pipe eg http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt076/slyt076.pdf

Comment: @pjc50 So "far the best way to do this" means "it exacts huge penalties of lower speed and loss of accuracy from software-induced errors and uncertainties", a bandwidth of 9 kHz and 50% CPU usage (if I read that article right). I don't think I agree. :)

Comment: It does allow for better accuracy than PWM (12 effective bits), although I'll admit that the settling time is too high for audio. That was literally the first plausible-looking search hit, other approaches should be viable.

Comment: @Asmyldof my AVR 1284P plays 39kHz/8-bit WAV straight from an SD card in real-time (double-buffered SD block-by-block, so 1k RAM needed only) without any audible noise with 20 MHz; hard to say if that's "reasonable quality" - with a 15kHz 2nd order lowpass filter to get rid of hi-freq noise, most people I asked didn't notice the difference with original 128kpbs MP3 at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little bit confusing, but I'll try my best to answer.

I think you are confusing the number of *discrete combinations* of bits, with the *average level*.

Let's start with your last question:

> If we convert 50k samples per second to 50,000 8 bit dithering patterns

If we do this, we would have to be able to generate 2<sup>8</sup>=256 different voltage levels after filtering. To do this, we must have room for 256 bits, meaning that you must generate a bitstream of 50k*256=12.8 Mbps. Far more than your 400 kbps.

This is because with 8 bits, there are 256 different combinations, but because you are oversampling and filtering, it's only the *number of bits* that counts, and that will be from 0 to 8. `0xAA` has the same average level as `0x55`, and `0xF0` etc.

A PWM with a faster rate will always generate a "better" signal. It's the raw bit rate that counts. Your raw PWM bit rate for a 32 kHz PWM signal with an 8 bit timing resolution is closer to 8 Mbps.

Comment: Ah ok, so using regulary 8 bit dithering patterns and assuming linear conversion, I will only get 8 different values, so it's only 3 bit like quality.

Comment: If so, I would be better of with 32kHz PWM with 8 bit resolution, which should theoretically give up to 8 bit but results in about 5-6 bits after filtering

Comment: @dronus Yes, you will be far better off using the PWM, both quality-wise, and implementation-wise.

Answer (score 6):

While the fixed-value start and stop bits at the output of the UART will impose some minor limitations on what you can achieve, it would certainly be possible to use a software delta-sigma modulator to produce the rest of the data bits from the analog value that you want to convert. You could even write the modulator so that it accounts for the fixed bits and optimizes the rest of the data around them.

However, 400 kHz is still not a great sampling rate for this kind of application, and you'll be trading off resolution for bandwidth. For example, if you want "telephone grade" audio at an effective 8-kHz sample rate, that's only 50 output bits per sample, or about 5-6 bits of effective resolution.

If you want "CD-quality" audio, you'd need to be operating the UART at several MHz in order to get both the bandwidth and resolution you need. For example, an oversampling ratio of 256x and a sample rate of 44.1 kHz (typical values for audio-grade DACs) would work out to 11.2896 MHz.

Comment: This basically sums it up. People often misunderstand what is meant when a frequency is mentioned. Some clock using frequency X doesn't mean you can output an accurate stream at frequency X. 400 kHz is enough to carry audio, but it won't be the quality you expect.

Comment: One may also attempt something similar using MOSI on SPI.

Comment: [`Software-only implementation:(...)it exacts huge penalties of lower speed and loss of accuracy
from software-induced errors and uncertainties`](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt076/slyt076.pdf)

Comment: @vaxquis: Yes, that author made that statement, but he never justified it or otherwise explained what "software-induced errors and uncertainties" might actually be. Having done it myself on several occasions, I can assure you that a software implementation can meet the timing and accuracy requirements just as well as a hardware implementation.